# How to apply styles for elements between class and hovered element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I try to optimize my calendar widget. I want to fill all elements between `selected_first` and `button:hover` with separate color (see code example):

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

div {
  counter-reset: btn;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  max-width: 200px;
}

button {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;;
}

button:before {
  counter-increment: btn;
  content: counter(btn);
}

button[value="selected_first"] {
  background: green !important;
}

button[value="selected_first"] ~ button, button:hover {
  background: blue;
}

button[value="selected_first"] ~ button:hover ~ button {
  background: #333;
   }
```

```html
<div>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button value="selected_first"></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
</div>
```

It works for me when the mouse is over on the button.
But it doesn't work when none of the buttons hovered.
It should look like that:
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl0zb.png)

but when none of the buttons hovered they still have a blue background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the hover on the parent element

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

div {
  counter-reset: btn;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  max-width: 200px;
}

button {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;;
}

button:before {
  counter-increment: btn;
  content: counter(btn);
}

button[value="selected_first"] {
  background: green !important;
}



div:hover button[value="selected_first"] ~ button,
div:hover button:hover {
  background: blue;
}
div:hover  button:hover ~ button {
  background: #333;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button value="selected_first"></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works for me. But I want to implement also the same logic, but for the `selected_last` element (hover should work only for element from `button:hover` and `selected_last`. And I ran into a problem that logic for `div:hover button:hover ~ button` will be different. Is it possible to solve this problem in one css file or I should also include js scripts?

Comment: @NullReferenceException you will try to update my answer consider the selected_last too

Comment: I tried to use the following code:
`

div:hover button[value="selected_last"] ~ button {
  background: #333 !important;
 }

div:hover button:hover ~ button {
  background: blue;
 }
`

it works fine only for `selected_last` element, but it brakes logic with `selected_first` element

Comment: @termani-afif, look at that here: https://jsfiddle.net/NullReferenceException/xvgyknoq/1/